# Path breadcrumbs based on several product fields

Tags: uri, breadcrumbs

I am using the Path Breadcrumbs module to create breadcrumbs for products. The problem is that these products can belong to several different categories (which can be set via special fields on a product page), say, flowers, animals and shrooms. When I make a rule for flowers ( 0 => '%node:field-flowers:0:pb-join:name') solely, it works only for flowers, of course (the flower products are shown as main -> flowers -> rose, but, say, animals are shown as main -> tiger). When I add another breadcrumb for animals, and its weight is smaller, it doesn't work at all. If I put it up to the 1st place, it works, but now flowers stop working.

I don't fully get how to use PB arguments & selection rules (if my question has anything to do with them). Where should I look?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? You have one vocabulary with 3 terms, or are there 3 different vocabularies? And you have 3 different fields field_flowers, field_animals and field_shrooms? Are these term reference fields? And why are your fields set up like this?